# Vimeo Oauth Authorization - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: javascript, access-token, vimeo

I am attempting to obtain an authorization token from Vimeo and am using an approach highlighed on the following Vimeo page:  https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication.    The problem I am having is I am constantly getting a `401 Unauthorized` message from Vimeo for some reason. Vimeo is configured to accept requests from this source domain.

Currently trying to get this POST to https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client to return an access token given both the headers I am sending and the JSON in the POST.  Two parameters to the Authorization headers that are supplied are from the Vimeo application setup:   Client Identifier and the Client Secret.
Unfortunately, currently getting a 401 Unauthorized response on each request.  Again, all of this is documented on the following Vimeo Web Page.  https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication which I have followed to the best of my ability.

```
 var access_token_data;

 function Authorize() {

     var authorize_data = {
         "grant_type": "client_credentials", "scope": "public"
     };

     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize/client",
         headers: {
             "Authorization": "basic base64_encode({Client Identifier}:{Client Secret})", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4"
         }, 
         data: JSON.stringify(authorize_data),
         cache: false,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         processData: false,
         success: function (data) {
             console.log("success");
             console.log(data);
             access_token_data = data.access_token;    

             alert("!!Access Token " + access_token_data)
         },
         error: function (data) {
             console.log("error");
             console.log(data);
         }
     });
 };
```

Comment: Is base64_encode really in your header?

Comment: Yes that is correct.   The content of the Authorization header is specified as the following:     basic base64_encode(x:y)

Comment: You are supposed to calculate the encoded base64 value yourself, and use that as the value for the `Authorization` header. The docs only show that as a placeholder so you (as the developer) knows that you need to encode your credentials with base64. You can use [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa) function in JS. So, in short, you need to encode the credentials, then set your Authorization header's value to `basic (resultOfTheEncoding)`.

Comment: nbokmans that resolved the issue and I am not getting an access token returned.  Thanks for your help.